# How to wait for subscribe inside subscribe?

Tags: angular, rxjs, subscription

I need to get an order with array of products. But getProduct() works later than i need, and all products undefined. I found out that nested subscribe its bad way, so what is the correct way to use mergeMap/switchMap

```
getOrder(id: string) {
  this.orderService
    .getOrder(id)
    .subscribe(order => {
      order.map(item => {
        data.push(item.payload.doc.data());
        return data;
      });
      this.order = data[0].products.map(x => this.getProduct(x))
    });
}

getProduct(id: string) {
  return this.productService
    .getProduct(id)
    .subscribe(product => product);
}

 getOrderById(id: string): Observable < any > {
  return this.afs
    .collection('orders', ref => ref.where('uid', '==', id))
    .snapshotChanges();
}
 getProductById(id: string): Observable < any > {
  return this.afs
    .collection('products', ref => ref.where('uid', '==', id))
    .valueChanges();
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Await recursive forkJoin in Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61462476/await-recursive-forkjoin-in-angular)

Answer (score 0):

I see that you have 2 observables here which are independent of each other.

1. getOrderById() 2) getProductById()

You can combine these two observables and subscribe it only once and also unsubscribe too. Something like this:

```
const orderByIdObservable = this.getOrderById();
const productByIdObservable = this.getProductById();

destroy$: Subject<any> = new Subject(); // This is used to destroy the subscription later

************************************************************
 *********** Using 'combineLatest' RXJS operator **********
************************************************************
// Combine the observables and destroy once done, in 1 shot.

combineLatest(orderByIdObservable,productByIdObservable)
  .pipe(
      takeUntil(this.destroy$),
      take(1)
   )
  .subscribe(
     ([orderByIdObservableData, productByIdObservableData]) => {
        if (orderByIdObservableData && productByIdObservableData) {
          // do your logic here
        }  
     }
  );

ngOnDestroy() {
   this.destroy$.next();
   this.destroy$.complete();
}



A) combineLatest - will combine all the observables and subscribe only once
B) takeUntil - this will keep subscribing until the destroy$ is completed/closed
C) take(1) - this will always take only the first value. You may or may not want to keep this
D) destroy$ - Use the Subject variable to destroy the service one the component is destroyed


************************************************************
 *********** Using 'mergeMap' RXJS operator **********
************************************************************

orderByIdObservable
  .pipe(
    mergeMap(productIdObsData => productByIdObservable.pipe(tap(data => !!data)),
    takeUntil(this.destroy$),
    take(1)
  )
  .subscribe(data => {
     console.log('Both the data merged into one', data);
     // here both the observables data are merged into one data variable
  })



A) mergeMap - if the data of the first observable is successfully subscribed, then only this mergeMap works otherwise the data after merging and subscribing is either null, undefined or some random object.
B) takeUntil - this will keep subscribing until the destroy$ is completed/closed
C) take(1) - this will always take only the first value. You may or may not want to keep this
D) destroy$ - Use the Subject variable to destroy the service one the component is destroyed
```

The advantage of combineLatest over mergeMap is you will have only one subscription and one unsubscription whereas in mergeMap you will have 2.